# Debug incoming http header for jypyter-notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a problem with CORS in my k8s jypyter-notebook deployment and I want to check incoming http requests headers.
How can I debug incoming http calls and headers in jypyter-notebook?